# When listing nouns, can you add だから between two elements to say "and, thus"?

Tags: nuances

When listing nouns like 「鶏肉とか、豚肉とか、牛肉ですよ。」, are you allowed to say something like 「鶏肉とか、豚肉とか、だから、牛肉ですよ。」 to indicate a thusly relationship between the other items, in the sense that if the previous elements are so, then obviously the next one makes sense to be there too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use だから there. Instead, you can say:

> - 鶏肉とか、豚肉とか、[あと](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7736)もちろん牛肉ですよ。
> - 鶏肉とか、豚肉とか、それから当然、牛肉ですよ。